# How to fetch entire row of Hibernate Inheritance Type SingleTable with Discriminator Column Value?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I have a parent class Electronics and subclass Camera and Mobile.I am using Hibernate Inheritance Single Table type. I want to get all electronic products along with their product type but upon fetching, I am unable to get the product type, which is the discriminator column as well. This is my first project using springboot and hibernate. Any help would be appreciated

**ELECTRONICS CLASS**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Table(name = "electronics")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "product_Type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class Electronics {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "CamIdGenerator", strategy = "com.virtusa.neuralhack.vlx.IdGenerator.CameraIdGenerator")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "CamIdGenerator")
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private String productId;
    
    private String askingPrice;

    @Column(name = "age")
    private String howOld;

    @Column(name = "model")
    private String model;

    @Column(name = "brand")
    private String brand;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    transient private String email;
    \\ getters and setter
```

**ELECTRONICS REPOSITORY**

```
@Override
    public List<Electronics> getDefaultElectronicProducts() {

        //System.out.println("repo check 1");
        Session currentSession = manager.unwrap(Session.class);
        
        //Query<Electronics> query = currentSession.createQuery("Select * from electronics Order By Rand() Limit 6", Electronics.class);
    
        //System.out.println("repo check 2");
        
        String query = "FROM Electronics ORDER BY RAND()";
        
        Query<Electronics> q =(Query<Electronics>) manager.createQuery(query,Electronics.class);
        
        q.setMaxResults(5);
        
        List<Electronics> defaultProductList = q.getResultList();
        
        //System.out.println("repo check 3");
        
        //System.out.println(defaultProductList.get(1));
        
        return defaultProductList;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have annotated the subclasses properly with the `@DiscriminatorValue` annotation containing the product type values? In that case, check the object types in the result list. You will see that depending on the value in the database, you will get instances of the subclasses. This is how you figure out the type. I suppose you could also model the product type as `@Column(name = "product_Type", insertable = false, updatable = false)` in the `Electronics` entity, but I would not recommend that to avoid possible confusion about the actual value.

Comment: Hii @ChristianBeikov, the discriminator value is being correctly loaded in the database. But my query is that, in the repository code, I have fetched list of electronics product i.e both camera and mobile will be present in it. I want to get product type along with rest of the details but I am unable to store the product type as no variable is defined explicitly in Electronics class to store this information. Can you help me with this???

Comment: What's the problem? Just add `@Column(name = "product_Type", insertable = false, updatable = false) private String productType` to your class, that should do the trick.